# Making the Set focus a variable for a SAP macro

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am making a macro which extracts information from SAP based on account and period. I have recorded it with the SAPGUI and it works fine with different variables (my goal is to have the same macro for different excel files based on a template). Where my problem comes from is when the number of accounts is changed, due to the fact that the set focus number is changing.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[70,13]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[70,13]").caretPosition = 8
```

Can someone tell me if its possible to make the number "13" in the brackets a variable and maybe how (the number is equal to count of the accounts + 12 and I have the number I need in a specific cell)

Regards,
Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would answer the first question *Can someone tell me if its possible to make the number "13" in the brackets a variable* like that

```
Dim pos as long

   pos = 13 
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[70," & CStr(pos) & "]").SetFocus
```